# Power BI - sum of time which is over 24 hours of a person working in 1 day

Tags: powerbi, dax

1st Nov    abc    12:32:44

2nd nov   abc      14:33:23

3rd Nov   abc      13:33:33

1st Nov    pqr      20:22:12

2nd nov   pqr      16:34;54

3rd Nov   pqr       15:46:33

1st Nov    mnb     20:52:19

2nd nov   mnb      18:34;58

3rd Nov   mnb     16:46:37

so now i want the sum of abc(1st, 2nd, 3rd Nov), pqr(1st, 2nd, 3rd Nov), mnb(1st, 2nd, 3rd Nov) resp.

ie: (12:32:44 + 14:33:23 + 13:33:33)  of abc of 1st, 2nd & 3rd Nov resp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To get addition of time which is over 24hrs (125:23:33) in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762519/to-get-addition-of-time-which-is-over-24hrs-1252333-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, it seems that you want to calculate hour:minutes:second, right? As I know, you need to convert your time(12:32:22) to second  at first, then calculate second based on month and person group

=(CALCULATE(sum(Table1[column1]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[month],Table1[id])))

Then you could refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33644.powerbi-aggregating-durationtime-in-dax.aspx to convert second to hh:mm:ss

Best Regards,

Zoe Zhi